# call local sources when use <Image> in React

Tags: react-native

I am trying to display images with ScrollView.

I have a code that works when I use images on the internet but not when they are local.
Can you tell me how to correct my code ?

I know the error comes from this : **source={{require(image)}}** but don't know how to write it correctly

```
const images = [
  './images/localImage1.jpg',
  './images/localImage2.jpg',
  //'https://someURLlink2.jpg',
  //'https://someURLlink2.jpg',
]

render() {
    let imageArray = []
    let barArray = []
    images.forEach((image, i) => {
      console.log(image, i)
      const thisImage = (
        <Image
          key={`image${i}`}
          //source={{uri: image}}
          source={{require(image)}}
          style={{ width: deviceWidth }}
        />
      )
      imageArray.push(thisImage)
```

Comment: try this `<Image source={require(image)} />`

Comment: @Emma : it triggers an error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `react-native` says

> In order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known
>   statically.

Read more in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

So the solution will be storing already required images in the array

```
const images = [
  require('./images/localImage1.jpg'),
  require('./images/localImage2.jpg')
]
```

and then call the image, like so;

```
render(){
        let imageArray = []
        let barArray = []
        images.forEach((image, i) => {
          console.warn(image, i)
          const thisImage = (
            <Image
              key={`image${i}`}

              source={image}
              style={{ width: deviceWidth }}
            />
          )
          imageArray.push(thisImage)
        })
        return imageArray;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch the image from the Internet and when fetching fails, display a local [one](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#defaultsource), please check out this solution:

```
  <Image
    style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
    source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}}
    defaultSource={{uri: require('./path/to/image.png')}}
  />
```

When your use-case is different and you only want to use the source prop, then please try this way:

```
const images = [
  require('./images/localImage1.jpg'),
  require('./images/localImage2.jpg'),
  'https://someURLlink2.jpg',
  'https://someURLlink2.jpg',
]

render() {
  let imageArray = []
  let barArray = []
  images.forEach((image, i) => {
    const thisImage = (
      <Image
        key={`image${i}`}
        source={{uri: image}}
        style={{ width: deviceWidth }}
       />
     )
  imageArray.push(thisImage)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `images.map((element,i)=>{
    return (
     <Image key={`image${i}`}
           source={element}
          style={{ width: deviceWidth }}/>
)
})`